# Linaro system boots to root without password

Tags: linux, passwords, root, auto-login

I installed a linaro system on my ARM chromebook, and it seems to autoboot to a root prompt. I've set a user password, and use it to login to the GUI, but with a simple Ctrl+Alt+F1, I can get to a logged in root prompt.

Setting a new root password with passwd does not help. I cannot logout of the root shell, it just returns me to a new login root shell.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. So this is how login works. There is an init script in `/etc/init/tty1.conf` which runs getty. Getty is a program that waits for login connections, and then authenticates a user. I initially thought getty was being run with autologin, and so I looked for a line in `/etc/init/tty1.conf` like

`exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 -a root tty1`

which means, open an 8bit terminal at 38400 baud and autologin the root user into tty1. But when I looked at the file, there was no `-a` option to autologin the root user. I'm stating this because `/etc/init/tty1.conf` should be the first place to look if others face the same issue.

Then I looked through the `/etc/init/` directory and found a file called `openvt.conf`. This had the following line:

`exec /bin/login -f root`

This was the culprit. The login command with the `-f` option automatically logs the user in without authentication.

Since the `openvt.conf` file is intended to be an upstart service, it has to be disabled in a particular way, although one can also simply delete the file. See [this askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services) about upstart. In short, either delete the `openvt.conf` file, or run

`echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/openvt.override`

and then root is no longer logged in automatically.